# How to apply a 3D gaussian filter with a kernel that peaks at 1?

Tags: python, math, scipy, gaussian

I am currently doing this to my array:

```
dataCube = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(dataCube, sigma, truncate=8)
```

But `gaussian_filter()` doesn't seem to have an option of ensuring that the peak/central value of the gaussian is 1. How can I do this?

Would multiplying `dataCube * np.sqrt(2*np.pi * sigma**2)` do the trick?

Comment: Take a look at the [updated answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723421/7932936).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just divide the whole kernel by the middle value, keeping the shape, but normalizing the peak to 1.

Comment: How do I know what the kernel and its middle value is, from `gaussian_filter()`? I suppose I could compare the raw dataCube to the filtered dataCube and try to figure it out from there, but I am working with a very large array and am doing this multiple times, so that seems like not the most efficient approach.

Comment: Do you need to use scipy filters? I would recommend using [cv2.filter2D()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) where you can specify the kernel, and use [cv2.getGaussianKernel()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#getgaussiankernel)

Comment: You could potentialy use [scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html) but than you have to generate your own gaussian filter. But in that case, you would have complete control over what the filter looks like

Comment: The kernel is calculated in scipy.ndimage.filters._gaussian_kernel1d